# Getting Values from Class Vector Variable

Tags: c++, raytracing

I'm trying to implement a raytracing algorithm for spheres in a given skeleton code

To calculate `Delta` I want to use get radius and center of the sphere. I'm getting an object of class `Scene` as import:

```
void render(image2D<float4>& framebuffer, const Scene& scene, float w_s, float 
f, const float4& background_color)
```

Class `Scene` does look like this:

```
class Scene
{
    Scene(const Scene&) = default;
    Scene& operator =(const Scene&) = default;
    std::vector<Sphere> spheres;
public:
    Scene() = default;
    void addSphere(const float3& c, float r);
};
```

So the class `Scene` includes a vector of `<Sphere>` where `Sphere` look like this:

```
struct Sphere
{
    float3 c;
    float r;
};
```

So I'm trying to get center and radius from import `Sphere` like this

```
std::cout << "Sphere radius: " << scene.spheres.(0).r << std::endl;
```

But I'm getting `scene.spheres` is private. We are not allow to change `.h` files. How could I handle this to get values for `c` and `r` for each object of sphere?

Comment: `scene.spheres.(0).r` is probably not valid syntax. You need to make `spheres` a public data member or write a getter for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have access to `spheres`, you could write:

```
std::cout << "Sphere radius: " << scene.spheres[0].r << std::endl;
```

or better:

```
for (auto& x: scene.spheres)
    std::cout << "Sphere radius: " << x.r << std::endl;
```

But with `spheres` being private to `Scene`, there's no way you could access it, unless you could change the definition of `Scene`, and either provide an iterator on `spheres`, or a getter for `spheres`, or make your render function a friend of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The class gives you no way to access its contents, and if you can't change it then you have no solution.

That's a very poorly designed class.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy, yet undeniably hacky way of going around your problem. I could not agree more with one of the comments saying that this is a poor design. But if you are not allowed to touch the header files, thus change the design of the `Scene` class, then here's what you can do.

Your raytracer should not need to have access to the concrete objects per say. All it needs is their attribute values. But you can't get that when the vector is private. That's a fact. But there's nothing stopping you from creating a duplicate vector and use that to pass the values in to the Scene vector **and** use that duplicated vector to access the attributes data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Sphere // can't touch this! 
{
    float c;
    float r;

    Sphere(float c_, float r_) : c(c_), r(r_)
    {;}
};

class Scene // can't touch this! 
{
    private:
        Scene(const Scene&) = default;
        Scene& operator = (const Scene&) = default;
        std::vector<Sphere> spheres;

    public:
        Scene() = default;
        void addSphere(float c, float r)
        {
            spheres.emplace_back(c,r);
        }
};

int main()
{
    Scene scene;

    std::vector<Sphere> spheres_duplicate = {{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0},{2.0,6.0}}; // duplicated vector.

    for (auto &&i : spheres_duplicate)
        scene.addSphere(i.c, i.r); // fill in the scene vector, so now you have 2 vectors. 

    std::cout << "Sphere radius: " << spheres_duplicate[0].r << std::endl; // access attributes from duplicated vector.
}
```

It works, but the problem with this solution is that you need to maintain 2 vectors. Not just one.

Example code: https://rextester.com/UEOKN35523